# A problem with a Borel set, a continuous function with a fixed point and a non-null fixed set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and $A$ be a Borel subset of $[0,1]$.
Consider a point $x_0 \in A$ such that for any neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ in $[0,1]$, we have $\mu(V \cap A)>0$.
Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function such that $f(x_0) = x_0$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\mu(f(A) \cap A)>0$ ?

*Remark*: If necessary, we can assume that $f$ is $C^1$, or even $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Sorry for this obvious question... it is improved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2899448/84284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong, because there is a counterexample (using a $C^\infty$ function $f$):

For example, you can choose $x_0=1/2, f(x) = 2x(1-x), A=[1/2,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=x_0$ for all $x$, $A=[0,1]$  to get a  counter example.

Comment: The answer of supinf works with the additional assumption $\mu(f(A))>0$ (that I forgot to write).