# A problem with a Borel set, a continuous function with a fixed point and a non-null fixed set, II

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

This post is the improvement of  [A problem with a Borel set, a continuous function with a fixed point and a non-null fixed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899355/a-problem-with-a-borel-set-a-continuous-function-with-a-fixed-point-and-a-non-n) by natural additional assumptions avoiding some easy counter-examples.

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and $A$ be a Borel subset of $[0,1]$.
Consider a point $x_0 \in A$ such that for any neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ in $[0,1]$, we have:

- $\mu([0,x_0] \cap V \cap A)>0$,
- $\mu([x_0,1] \cap V \cap A)>0$.

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a polynomial function such that:

- $f(x_0) = x_0$,
- $\mu(f(A))>0$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\mu(f(A) \cap A)>0$ ?

*Remark*: If possible, we can consider the more general cases $f \in C^{\infty}$, $C^1$ or even $C^0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a counterexample.

Consider the function $f(x) = x/2+1/4$ and $x_0=1/2$.
For our construction, we need the set
$$
B= \bigcup_{n\geq 3} (2^{-2n-1},2^{-2n}).
$$
Notice that $\frac12 B \cap B = \emptyset$ and that $B$ contains open intervals arbitrarily close to $0$.
We choose
$$
A= (x_0+B) \cup (x_0-B).
$$
This symmetry guarantees the conditions involving the intervals $[0,x_0],[x_0,1]$.
Then, it can be shown that
$$
f(A) = (x_0 +B/2) \cup (x_0 - B/2).
$$
Then it follows from the above that $f(A)\cap A=\emptyset$.

Comment: @nicomezi the set $\{x_0 - b | b\in B \}$

Comment: Thank you.... I am running at low speed today. Your construction seems fine but I am not sure.

Comment: Correct! Your construction extends to any [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping).

Comment: Perhaps what I had in mind when I wrote this question is the following: if $f$ is ergodic and if $A,B$ are Borel sets with $\mu(A)>0$ and $\mu(B)>0$, then by definition of [ergodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity) there is $n>0$ such that $\mu(f^n(A) \cap B)>0$. I don't know if this can help for an other natural improvement of the question...